# Finding the Probability of an Event Happening: Another Interpretation?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

I want to find the following probability: If there are 10 people and we select randomly 3 people to form a group. If you and your friend are within these 10 people, what is the probability that neither you nor your friend are chosen?

I think the problem is solved as this:

The total number ways to select that you and your friend not getting chosen is:
$8 \times 7 \times 6 = 336$

The total number ways to select 3 from 10 people is:
$10 \times 9 \times 8 = 720$

Therefore, the probability is $P(Event) = \frac{8 \times 7 \times 6}{10 \times 9 \times 8} = \frac{336}{720} = \frac{7}{15} \approx 46.67\%$.

My question is: Can we interpret the product $\frac{8 \times 7 \times 6}{10 \times 9 \times 8}$ as the probability of **three mutually exclusive events** multiplied together? Something like $P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(A) \times P(B) \times P(C) = \frac{8}{10} \times \frac{7}{9} \times \frac{6}{8}$. If so, what are these events? Is there a general rule of doing so?

Comment: Total number of ways to select $3$ from $10$ people is $^{10}C_3 = \frac{10!}{3! \cdot 7!} = 120$ No? $10 \times 9 \times 8 = 720$ is the number of ways of arranging the $3$ selected persons.

Comment: Mutually exclusive events can't have a sum of probabilities greater than $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P_1$, $P_2$, and $P_3$ be the three people who are selected. Let $A$ be the event that $P_1$ is neither you no your friend. Similarly, $B$ is the event that $P_2$ is not you are your friend, and $C$ is the event that $P_3$ is neither you nor your friend. Then
$$
P(A\cap B\cap C)=P(A)P(B\mid A)P(C\mid A\cap B)=\frac8{10}\times \frac79\times \frac68
$$
Note that you have to use conditional probabilities to compute $P(A\cap B\cap C)$ since $A,B$ and $C$ are not independent.

The reason that $P(A)=8/10$ is because $P_1$ is equally likely to be any of the $10$ people, of which $8$ are neither you nor your friend.

The reason that $P(B\mid A)=7/9$ is because, conditional on $P_1$ not being you or your friend, there are $9$ people remaining, of which $7$ are neither you nor your friend. Similarly, $P(C\mid A\cap B)=6/8$ because given that the first two people were neither you nor your friend, there are six favorable possibilities out of the remaining eight equally likely people.